# Is the Fire Shield a damage-dealing spell for the purpose of the Imbued Wood Focus (Fernian Ash)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, damage

The [*Fire Shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-shield) spell (PHB, p. 242; emphasis mine) states:

> [...] In addition, whenever a creature within 5 feet of you hits you with a melee attack, the shield erupts with flame. The attacker takes 2d8 **fire damage** from a warm shield, or 2d8 cold damage from a cold shield.

The [*Imbued Wood Focus (Fernian Ash)*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/imbued-wood-focus) (ERLW, p. 277; WGE, p. 114; emphasis mine) states:

> [...] When you cast a damage-dealing spell using this item as your spellcasting focus, you gain a +1 bonus to one fire damage roll of the spell.

**Does that +1 fire damage applies the first time a Wizard *does damage* with his Fire Shield?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Damage-dealing spell" is not a keyword in 5e, I can see two possible interpretations;

1. Fire Shield is a damage dealing spell as it can deal damage
2. Fire Shield is not a damage dealing spell as it does not deal damage directly but instead creates an effect that deals damage

It's up to your DM to make a ruling, there is no resolution from the official rules.

FWIW (nothing?) dndbeyond tags Fire Shield with the "Damage" tag.